How to rank a date field?
My table looks like this:



Project
Date




EO124
07-25-2023


E0124
08-01-2023


EO124
10-05-2023


EO124
10-12-2023


EO124
11-10-2023


EO124
11-17-2023


EO124
12-01-2023



In my table, there are multiple project names and other fields also. My requirement is to rank all projects' End Date in ascending order.
I tried like this but failed.
SELECT TOP  
  [Date],
  [Project]
  RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [Project_Name] ORDER BY [End_Date]asc) Rank
FROM Table_Name


Is your date column text?

A [mcve] is supposed to include the expected result too.

Note that tables have columns, not filelds. (But a date has a year field, a month field and a day field...)

"I tried like this but failed" what happened? You have a weird TOP with no number, that's a syntax error.

And there is a comma missing after the column [Project]. Is this SQL Server? (You should always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS.)

@TimBiegeleisen date column is Date Datatype. I want to Rank all date of each project. .

@jarlh I want to rank all dates of each project.

Hi - you need to update your question with a result table showing what you want to achieve, based on the sample data you’ve provided.

And again: "I tried like this but failed" - how did it fail? We have pointed out syntax errors in your query. If you fix them, does your query do what it is supposed to do?

Please read [mre] to help improve your question and get a better chance of a positive response.  Also; Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.


I tried like this but failed.

Descriptions like this give us no information at all.
The first "fail" (as pointed out in the comments) is the error "Incorrect syntax near 'Date'." - because you have not supplied a number after TOP. Usually a homework question like this will want the "top ranked item" and you would use TOP 1 but I will use TOP 100 for now - of which more shortly.
Your next "fail" (also pointed out in the comments) is the error "Incorrect syntax near ')'." - because you have missed the comma after [Project] / before RANK. The results of RANK is essentially a column in your results and needs to be in the list of columns to return. Items in Lists are separated by commas.
The next "fail" comes as two messages - "Invalid column name 'Project_Name'." and "Invalid column name 'End_Date'.". These are in your OVER clause for RANK. You haven't given us those columns in your example. I assumed you meant [Project] and [Date], which gave me code that looked like this
SELECT TOP  100
  [Date],
  [Project],
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Project] ORDER BY [Date] asc) [Rank]
FROM Table_Name

which generates the results
Date        Project Rank
2023-08-01  E0124   1
2023-07-25  EO124   1
2023-10-05  EO124   2
2023-10-12  EO124   3
2023-11-10  EO124   4
2023-11-17  EO124   5
2023-12-01  EO124   6

Which brings me back to the number after TOP - note there is more than 1 row with a rank of '1' - that is because of your typing error using a 0 instead of O in your 2nd data item. Once you have corrected that you could use TOP 1 but that does not take into account multiple projects. So what you want is a sub-query (or table variable, or temporary table, or CTE) that you can filter with a WHERE clause e.g.
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
    [Date],
    [Project],
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Project] ORDER BY [Date]) [Rank]
    FROM @Table_Name
) sub_query
WHERE [Rank] = 1;

